# Using Selenium IDE and latest Firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox

I want to use the Selenium IDE add-on with the latest version of Firefox. I tried this with Selenium 2.9.1.1, but it didn't work so I downgraded to Firefox 49.0.

I am wondering if this is possible?  I am overwhelmed by all the Selenium options and cannot figure out what the best approach is.

Is there a Selenium 3.0 in beta that I can use?  Or do I need to use a beta or nightly build from Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

+1 for overwhelmed here, I feel you! :)

Best approach is an approach which is robust and just..works imho. I like keeping my Selenium+Geckodriver on the latest version (to get the new features) ;but I usually stick with the actual browser for a while. Don't want to become a free beta-tester for the big Corps. :) You can have some manual testers double-check the latest Firefox version just to be safe; but here's a combo that **will work for you 100%**:

> *** FirefoxSetup *** Firefox 53.0.1, GeckoDriver v16, Selenium v3.4.0

Geckodriver is the driver you need to run FireFox. And you also need to tell Selenium where you placed the executable:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "C:\\projects\\test\\geckodriver.exe");                          
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Best of luck!

Comment: I am having trouble installing Selenium 3.4. I click on the java executable and it does nothing.  I have at least one version of Java installed (Java 8 update 121 - 64 bit).

Comment: Hi Aaron, it is rather easy to find your java version if unsure. Just click on start and search for 'about java'. Unless you have a MAC you can do it from the cmd there. You don't need to execute the jar just include it in your project (so make a folder called lib in your project and just copy/paste your selenium 3.4.0 there). Finally, google 'add external jar' if you are using Eclipse as an IDE, or let me know what you are using.

Comment: I think I really want to use the old Selenium 2.9 IDE that integrated with the browser. I don't want to create a special project (and possibly install Eclipse with Java).  I guess I'll do it eventually, but meanwhile it seems like a big waste of time.  And if there is any way to keep the old system working, I'd greatly prefer it.

Comment: Eventually it is not a waste of time but doing things right. Using IDE neither will teach you anything nor will be useful for the future. I'm afraid with such an old version of Selenium you won't find a reliable working combo.  If I was you, I will google and watch youtube videos on Selenium + Java tutorials. Neverthelses, best of luck!